# Jeep Wrangler shudders/stalls when put in gear after cold start

Tags: jeep, stall, cold-start

I have a 2012 Jeep Wrangler Unlimited auto trans, around 80,000 miles.

This started a few months ago. When I start it cold, like after sitting overnight, it starts fine, sounds fine.

But when I put it in gear (D or R), it either shudders and RPM's drop and feels like it's going to stall, or it actually stalls. It usually does a full stall when it's really cold (like below 30 degrees). Otherwise, it does the shudder.

When it stalls, it starts right back up, and then it is OK - I can put it in gear and it acts normally.

The only other thing, potentially related, is that it seems to run a little rough when moving very slowly (like < 5 mph). But at idle it seems OK.

I changed the transmission fluid, and that made no difference.

Any ideas about what to look at?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Have you had the codes read? That might at least give you a place to start looking. Has it been serviced regularly?

Comment: I had it to the dealer and they said no codes were stored. I did have a check englne light a few months ago, which they said was a cylinder misfire, but it cleared. I have regular oil changes, and some recommended maintenance, such as transmission fluid change. They tried that to see if it would help. The next recommended maintenance is sparks and wires.

Comment: Same here. 2012 JK Unlimited, 84,000 miles. Happens on the first start of the day. Doesn't matter if I let it warm up for 1min, 5 min or 15 min. Noticed it when it turned cold on the east coast(Dec). If I put it into reverse and keep my foot on the break it stalls. If I shift to reverse and quickly take my foot off the break it will sound like its going to stall, but doesn't. And then it is fine ... never will happen for the rest of the day. Just that first start, first shift to reverse only.

Comment: Sounds the same. A friend suggested replacing the camshaft sensor but I haven’t had a chance to do that yet.

Comment: IAC should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Chrysler has found the torque converter is a problem going into lock up mode when putting in reverse making it sputter shudder and stall.

Go to the link below to page 21-528. About half way down the page it shows Engine stalls when shifting into R or D. It will show no codes - the techs need to read the manual, not their tester as usual.

http://www.lx.abodiesonline.com/Manuals/NAG1%20Manual.pdf

Comment: Hi Jay, Welcome to the site and thanks for the info. However, your answer needs just a little qualification: Is there a link to the info you refer to about Chrysler? or are you a Chrysler serviceman? Certainly sounds like this would cause the issue described, but before we blame Chrysler it would be better to qualify the answer first :)

Comment: Are you familiar with a recall number for this issue? It seems to me that getting going in cold weather might be important to a Jeep.